# XDebug setup in the VS Code

Tags: php, docker-compose, xdebug, xdebug-2

I'm new to xdebug world and therefore setup below is mostly copied from tutorials. Unfortunately, the PHP debugging doesn't start to work. Don't stop on breakpoint. I don't understand what is missing.

**My setup:**
VS Code machine: 192.168.1.220

**Dev website (site is fully functional):**
Address locally: 192.168.1.182:8100 or http://myNasServer:8100,\
Public phpinfo (reverse proxy " Nginx Proxy Manager"):  https://intranet.adplus.ee/info.php 
The website runs in a docker container and is using PHP 5.6.40 (it is an old app and requires this php)

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_secret_pw_shh
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: devuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: devpass
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --sql_mode=""
  web:
    container_name: php_web
    build:
        context: ./php
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/intra/:/var/www/html/
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

XDEBUG config in local.ini file (Netbeans suggested configuration)

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="./xdebug.log"
xdebug.show_exception_trace=1
```

Vs Code launch configuration

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "log": true           
        },
        {
            "name": "Lauch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try xdebug_info() it will help you trace the problem. Also inspect your container that runs PHP for any logs from xdebug

Comment: xdebug_info() is for Xdebug 3. For the PHP 5.6 the last Xdebug version is 2.5.5

Comment: 1) What Xdebug log has to say about it? Does it tries to connect to the debug client at all? 2) Since it's Docker ... you should really have this: `xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"` or use the IP of the host if you prefer (which most likely will change each time you reboot). I do not see `xdebug.remote_host`, which means it defaults to `localhost` .. 3) Post your Xdebug section of the `php_info()` output anyway -- it will show the actual live settings.

Comment: I've added `debug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"`. The log looks:
`Log opened at 2023-10-03 12:36:43
I: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
W: Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9003', getaddrinfo: No such file or directory.
E: Could not connect to the client. :-(
Log closed at 2023-10-03 12:36:43 `

Link to php_info() is in my original post.

Comment: Cannot resolve the host? Try adding this to your docker compose file: `extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`. No other ideas from me. **P.S.** BTW, are you on Linux? Do you run rootless docker?

Answer (score 0):

Your Xdebug configuration uses everything for Xdebug 2, and not 3, which you're most likely using. You need a newer tutorial, or read the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide).

I would also suggest you read the official documentation, right on Xdebug's website: https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug — which also links to a 5 minute video on how to do it with Docker: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIGdBSD6zvU

Comment: but he's using PHP 5.6.4. That version of PHP does not support xdebug 3

Comment: My Xdebug version: This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans

Comment: Neither PHP 5.6 (or even 7!) or Xdebug 2 are supported any more. Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

From what you written I understand you run your VS Code IDE and your PHP on different machines. Since you mention `myNasServer` I suspect you have your PHP files mapped via SMB or NFS to your local workstation.
Since Xdebug *connects to* the IDE you need to tell it either with `xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.220` or enable `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`.

Although from the log you posted it seems that Xdebug is indeed trying to connect, you can also try to add `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` that will start debugger regardless of the trigger cookie/get parameters.

Also, I want to extend my heartfelt sympathy for you needing to work on a PHP5 application... :)